# QWidget created in an aux method does not show/draw

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget

I have a `QWidget` based class that I need to instantiate from another object.

If I create the widget in the body of its parent widget class it is all good:

```
new NodeWidget(rootItem, this); // this works
```

But when I use the aux method the widget is created, but never drawn.

```
rootItem->createWidget(this); // internally rootItem does the same thing as above
```

The method itself:

```
void createWidget(QWidget * target) {
     if (!_ui) _ui = new NodeWidget(this, target);
...
}
```

The way I see it, both approaches do the same thing, but the first one works while the second one does not. The `NodeWidget` constructor runs, but the widget does not appear in the parent widget and the paintEvent is never called. Any ideas why?

EDIT: This is certainly odd, I noticed that the following line:

```
new QPushButton(this);
```

works when called in the constructor of the parent widget, but not when called from the mousePress event. What IS the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you call *show()* for your custom widget?

If the child widget is created after it's parent is already showed the parent-child relationship can't show the child too, so you need to explicitly call *show()*.

But when the widget is added in the constructor, the parent isn't showed yet and then when the parent is showed it automatically shows all the children that were not explicitly hidden.

Comment: I may have incorrectly assume that Qt would automatically "show" new widgets every time the UI is redrawn. Will test it now.

Comment: Now I am getting a segmentation fault when I call `show()`, I check the pointer returned from `new` and it is valid, so what's with the segfault?

Comment: You need to debug your code, we can't guess why you get segmentation fault, if you can't fix it you need to show more code (check for uninitialized/invalid pointers into the class you instantiate)

Comment: Well, the `createWidget` method actually runs through a tree hierarchy, calling the same method for all its children. With only a single root child the sole `NodeWidget` is shown, e.g. the method works, but it fails if there are children. I debugged it, but all I got was that it crashes on the `show()` method for the first child, I output the pointer before calling `show()` and it is valid, so `new` doesn't fail...